# Regex to find a particular word in html

Tags: html, regex

I want to find all occurrences of "color: " inside my html below. But problem is that I get one previous character as well selected.

Note: I dont want "background-color:"

Please help

Test [link](http://regexr.com/?385gg) - http://regexr.com/?385gg

HTML

```
<div id="divSection">
  <div class="section-topcurve" style="background-color: rgb(224, 99, 32);">
    <div class="app-input" id="Div11" onclick="CellDoubleClick(this,50)" style="color: rgb(156, 117, 156); background-color: rgb(224, 99, 32);">Item 1</div>
"asd-color:rgb(156,2,3);
"color: rgb(156, 117, 156);
    <span class="additem">
      <a id="Section" href="" onclick="return AddnewItem(this.id);">add item</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="section-nocurve" id="divSection1390991308640" style="background-color: rgb(189, 114, 73); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
    <div class="app-input" id="cellSection1390991308640" style="background-color: rgb(189, 114, 73); color: rgb(143, 24, 143);">New Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-btmcurve" id="divSection1390991552843" style="background-color: rgb(189, 114, 73); color: rgb(143, 24, 143);">
    <div class="app-input" id="cellSection1390991552843" style="background-color: rgb(189, 114, 73);">New Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `[^-](color:)` Color is now in a capture group and you can get the value of the first capture group out of the match

Comment: I want it till the first occurrence of ";"

Comment: Then use `[^-](color:[^;]*)` or `[^-](color:.*);`

Comment: [It’s a lot of work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
[\s"](color:\s{0,1}.*?\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cv195UJ9fPgawHrh)